# how to receive all days between 2 dates in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

consider that i have 2 dates like below in my view :

```
{{$property->start_date }} //which is for example 3/20/219
```

and another date

```
{{$property->end_date }} //which is for example 3/28/219
```

now i want to some how print these 8 days of difference as 8 col-lg-1 some how like below code

```
@while($property->start_date  <= $property->end_date)

//here i want to print dates in col-lg-1 i dont know how to access the day and if the while loop is working right or no
```

how can i achieve that in blade considering this that i am doing this in my view and is it reasonable at all to do it in view or not .

Comment: There is a way called strtotime

Comment: I know, Wordpress is doing that a lot. But... Do *not* suppress warnings: `@while`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `CarbonPeriod` from `Carbon`

something like this

```
$ranges = CarbonPeriod::create('2019-03-01', '2019-03-31');
```

To print each date you can use the loop

```
foreach ($ranges as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Or you can convert it to array as well

```
$dates = $ranges->toArray();
```

Comment: most of answers would work but this is the laravel form and it shows the current selected day too which is what i was looking for !! thanks @punit gajjar

Comment: @Farshad, Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

**Return all dates between two dates in php:**

**Using `DatePeriod` and `DateTime`:**

```
$begin = new DateTime($property->start_date); // your start date 2019-03-20
$begin = $begin->modify( '+1 day' );
$end = new DateTime($property->end_date); // your end date 2019-03-28

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach ($daterange as $date) {
    echo '<pre>'.$date->format('Y-m-d').'<pre>'; 
}
```

**Output:**

```
2019-03-21
2019-03-22
2019-03-23
2019-03-24
2019-03-25
2019-03-26
2019-03-27
```

**Using `strtotime`:**

```
// Declare two dates 
$Date1 = $property->start_date; // 2019-03-20
$Date2 = $property->end_date; // 2019-03-28

// Declare an empty array 
$array = array(); 

// Use strtotime function 
$start = strtotime($Date1. '+1 day'); 
$end = strtotime($Date2. '-1 day'); 

// Use for loop to store dates into array 
// 86400 sec = 24 hrs = 60*60*24 = 1 day 
for ($currentDate = $start; $currentDate <= $end; $currentDate += (86400)) { 

    $Store = date('Y-m-d', $currentDate); 
    $array[] = $Store; 
} 

// Display the dates in array format
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '<pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2019-03-21
    [1] => 2019-03-22
    [2] => 2019-03-23
    [3] => 2019-03-24
    [4] => 2019-03-25
    [5] => 2019-03-26
    [6] => 2019-03-27
)
```

I hope it would helpful.

Comment: ok thanks i will let you know when i try it and some thing is that can i count the days with date between these 2 ?? for example i wanna print out like these 3/27/2019 - 3/28/2019 / 3-29-2019 like these sorting the days difference between 2

Comment: You want to print the complete dates instead of counts?

Comment: @InzamamIdrees , OP wants this with Laravel, where I would suggest to use Carbon instead of DateTime. :-)

Comment: @PunitGajjar yes but carbon just give the number of different days no ?? i could not get the sort of days like this with carbon or i dont know the way :D

Comment: @Farshad try `strtotime` or `DateTime` to get the arrays of dates between two dates.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get date diff , you can use `Carbon` and `diffInDays` .

```
$date1 = Carbon::parse($property->start_date);
$date2 = Carbon::parse($property->end_date );

$diff = $date1->diffInDays($date2);
dd($diff);
```

Comment: It is better to do in controller and send data to view with your all required data . It is better I think

Answer (score 1):

You can try this on template directly (only if there no way or if it's difficult to pass it from controller to view)

```
@php
    $date1 = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-01-31 10:15:23');
    $date2 = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-02-15 10:15:23');
    $diff = $date1->diffInDays($date2);
@endphp

<div>{{$diff}}</div>
```

but if you do it in controller and send it to template it would be better

Comment: thanks but this will show the number of different days though i want to sort the days difference 2019-03-21    2019-03-22   2019-03-23 like this

Comment: ok, then you should try `CarbonPeriod`, check this link
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period